# Show a list of subcategories for current category

Tags: categories, child-categories

I'm trying to develop a simple product catalog using categories; I use Transcribe plugin, also.

I've got main categories CAT1 (id4), CAT2 (id5), CAT3 (id6), CAT4 (id7) and subcategories of CAT1: SUBCAT1, SUBCAT2, SUBCAT3. Every main category have its own template page, for example when the user select CAT1 go to page:
http://develop/products/group/C4/
On that page I need to show a list of CAT1 subcategories: SUBCAT1, SUBCAT2 and SUBCAT3. I wanna do it dynamically.
Now, I can show my subcategories list right set parent_id manually...

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="products" style="linear"}
    {if parent_id=="4"}
        {exp:transcribe:replace name="category_{category_url_title}"}<br />
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

I'm able to get the current main category ID...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1"}
    {categories}
        {category_id}
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I wonder if there's a way to combine these informations and, simply, get "SUBCAT1, SUBCAT2, SUBCAT3" as output without use any plugins, when I'm on the CAT1 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Gw Code Categories` like as below:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories cat_id="{segment_3}"}
    {cat_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

OR if you want to use category url title then:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories cat_url_title="{segment_3}"}
    {cat_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Output:

```
-> CAT1
   -> SUBCAT1
   -> SUBCAT2
   -> SUBCAT3
```

If you don't want to show the "CAT1" category, you can add the incl_self parameter like so: `incl_self="no"`.

Comment: First of all, Jainil, thanks so much for your help!
I prefer to use less plugins I can, but I've already hear about GWcode, so I give it a try.
It work fine in EE3 (the old stable version with a self-made porting, the EE3 beta also): I can do what i want with categories list.
But it does not work with Transcribe plugin: I must use `{exp_transcribe:replace name="category_{cat_url_title}"}` inside `{exp:gwcode_categories ...}` ...But it seems that Transcribe is executed first GWcode generate his output loop..
I just started to use EE and I'm really confused..

Comment: Finally, I have discovered [EE **parse** parameter](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/plugins.html) ... I've added `parse="inward"` to my `{ext:gwcode_categories}` tag and all works fine! Thank you!